# Lat/Long Distance Comparison

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having some trouble with figuring out how to do this. What I have is a list of 160K locations on an Access table with lat and long coordinates for each. I am trying to find out how to create a column that compares 1 item on the list to the rest of the items to bring back the closest distance in miles.

I've figured out how to use the haversine formula to make a 1 to 1 comparison but I am lost in  trying to automate the rest.

This is basically what I want to try to produce...

```
Loc_ID  Loc_Lat     Loc_Long     Min_Miles_Away
1       33.537214   -81.687378   674.48
4       42.16584    -87.845117   11.83
5       41.99558    -87.869057   11.83
6       41.85325    -89.486883   83.75
```

Explanation to the table...
Location 1 is closest to location 5 (674.48 miles apart)
Location 4 is closest to location 5 (11.83 miles apart)
Location 5 is closest to location 4 (11.83 miles apart)
Location 6 is closest to location 5 (83.75 miles apart)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cartesian join, i.e. a join without a where. It will join each row with every other row. You can do that by simply writing the SQL into the SQL view of the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM locations a, locations b
```

Next you can calculate the distance (I guess you have that code already, so just insert the function) on that table.
Finally you can group by MIN.

```
SELECT loc_id, loc_lat, loc_long, MIN(calulated_distance) as min_miles_away
FROM myCalculatedQuery
```